# Can I switch two 12v sources with 5 pin relay?

Tags: relay, automotive, 12v, switching

I'm installing a stereo in an RV and would like to maintain default behavior of having the stereo receive power on vehicle accessory power/ignition, but also be controlled by a switch in the RV for use when the vehicle is not in use. These are the requirements:

- When the RV switch is OFF, the stereo turns on and off with vehicle accessory power.
- When the RV switch is ON, the stereo remains powered regardless of vehicle operation.
- The source of power when the vehicle is running does not matter, but it must utilize the RV batteries when it isn't.

Would there be any problems with utilizing a ~30A 5 pin relay to achieve this? The stereo utilizes an external amp, so it will be drawing very little power.

[image: 12v 5 pin relay power supply switching]

Answer (score 1):

It will work just as you have it drawn.  But why not just use a SPDT switch to switch between house power and accessory power?  Simpler, cheaper, more reliable, no down side immediately apparent...

Comment: Yep, that's definitely an option. The reason I am considering the relay approach is due the DC switching being almost entirely contained within a marine style breaker/switch panel. I could add a separate switch panel for these use cases, but so far this is the only special case.

Comment: I guess the advantage of the relay is that it's automatic.  You don't accidentally run the RV battery flat listening to the radio for hours, even thoigh you were plugged into the house at the time.

Answer (score 0):

If the source of power when the vehicle is running doesn't matter, I'd just power the stereo from the RV "house" battery- why complicate things?

Comment: Mostly for the end user experience. I could use a SPST to turn the stereo on and off manually or as [the other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/391255/196042) suggests, use a SPDT to switch the two power sources. I'm still considering both of these, but if I use the relay approach, I can put the stereo switch within my main DC marine style circuit/switch panel and not have to introduce a separate switch panel elsewhere.